# Using Hausdorff Distance with Time

Tags: algorithms

My company tracks objects.  I have developed an algorithm that tries to identify objects that are attached to each other.  It does this in real time and starts trying to identify objects after roughly 5 minutes of travel.

Currently this uses some basic time filtering plus a Hausdorff distance algorithm to ensure it tracks objects that leave at roughly the right time and follow roughly the right path/trajectory.  Note that these tracked object will certainly report their time & position at irregular intervals. (Between 30s and 5minutes per update)

This alone achieves a great level of accuracy.  However in certain cases four objects will leave at roughly the same time.  Two primary objects each with an attached secondary object (i.e. 2 + 2). In this case the system fails.

I thought that if I could somehow include time in the Hausdorff distance it may help improve the accuracy.

Is this actually a viable solution and how might I modify my Hausdorff algorithm to also include a time series parameter?

Failing this is there a suitable machine learning algorithm that would be worth looking at?